# Possible to use exact differential to prove Euler's test?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that when we want to prove an equation is exact differential, we use $$\frac{d^2Q}{dxdy}=\frac{d^2Q}{dydx}$$

But I wonder why?
$$dQ=\frac{dQ}{dx}dx+\frac{dQ}{dy}dy$$
Then differential again $$d^2Q=\frac{d^2Q}{dx^2}dx^2+\frac{d^2Q}{dy^2}dy^2+\frac{d^2Q}{dydx}dydx+\frac{d^2Q}{dxdy}dxdy$$ correct?but
How to prove $$\frac{d^2Q}{dxdy}=\frac{d^2Q}{dydx}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards... you are usually given

$$ A(x,y) dx + B(x,y)dy$$
and want to know if it is an exact differential.
If $Q$ exists so that
$$ dQ=A(x,y) dx + B(x,y)dy$$
then you need
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = A(x,y), ~~~
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} = B(x,y)
$$
If this is the case, you need
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} \tag 1$$
I.e.
$$
\frac{\partial A(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial B(x,y)}{\partial x} 
$$

Note: The equation (1) is true under fairly weak continuity requirements for any $Q$ and is not specific to exact differentials.

Comment: Thanks. What are the fairly weak continuity requirements for any Q ?

Comment: That the first derivatives be continuously differentiable (going from memory).